# on bslib package and shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, bslib

This a question on bslib, by the way, a great package.

I'd like to know if it is primarily intended for shiny and flexdashborad or it will be also operative with shinydashboard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

`bslib` is not intended to be used with `shinydashboard` and should instead be leveraged in conjunction with `shiny`. Granted, you shouldn't have issues using `bslib` for `flexdashboard`, please see the [Theming {flexdashboard} writeup](https://rstudio.github.io/flexdashboard/articles/theme.html). To elaborate more on Shiny, some additional thoughts:

- `shinydashboard` provides new verbs for theming your Shiny apps for use with Bootstrap 3 + AdminLTE v2.4 HTML templates
- `bslib` makes it easy to customize "stock" Shiny apps with modern Bootstrap 4 (or 5) themes - This is accomplished through the introduction of Sass variables for use with Shiny and R Markdown and `bslib` pre-packages Bootswatch themes without the need to load other packages
- The customization of your `bslib` themes can be further expanded by using Sassy CSS (you'll need a custom *.scss file as opposed to a *.css file)

The [RinteRface](https://rinterface.com/#packages) team have done an excellent job developing the `bs4Dash` package to solve the problem that I believe you're attempting to solve, i.e., using newer Bootstrap themes on top of the `shinydashboard` framework. More on the `bs4Dash` package:

- `shinydashboard` is the basis of `bs4Dash` with 1:1 support so upgrading your old apps to `bs4Dash` can be accomplished by simply changing `library(shinydashboard)` to `library(bs4Dash)`
- `bs4Dash` brings Bootstrap 4 + AdminLTE v3.1 dependencies to your traditional `shinydashboard` templates
- On the *Introduction* page of the `bs4Dash` pkgdown site, there is a table [comparing the features](https://rinterface.github.io/bs4Dash/articles/bs4Dash.html) of `shinydashboard`, `shinydashboardPlus`, and `bs4Dash` (the latter two being developed by the RinteRface team)

If you're seeking a package like `bslib` specifically for customizing the theme and styling of your `bs4Dash` apps, [check out the {fresh} package](https://dreamrs.github.io/fresh/articles/vars-bs4dash.html) from the Parisian  [dreamRs](https://www.dreamrs.fr/) team!